# Access Violations using Poppler-Qt6

Tags: c++, poppler

I'm attempting to build a minimal C++ application in Visual Studio using poppler-qt6 and running into issues with runtime access violation exceptions.

The following, modelled after a poppler-qt6 [example](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/master/qt6/tests/test-poppler-qt6.cpp), works:

```
#include <poppler/qt6/poppler-qt6.h>
#include <Qt6/QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <Qt6/QtWidgets/QLabel>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
        const wchar_t* wCharFilepath = L"C:\\poppler-test\\test.pdf";
        QString qFilepath = QString::fromWCharArray(wCharFilepath);
            
        std::unique_ptr<Poppler::Document> documentPtr = Poppler::Document::load(qFilepath);
        if (!documentPtr) {
            std::cout << "Failed to load document\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "loaded pdf\n";
        }
    
        std::unique_ptr<Poppler::Page> pagePtr = documentPtr->page(0);
        
        if (!pagePtr) {
            std::cout << "Failed to get page\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "got pagePtr\n";
        }
    }
```

However, the inclusion of `return app.exec()` and/or `QLabel* l = new QLabel();` at the end of the main method causes an access violation at the `Poppler::Document::load()` line.

The following runs without issue:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel* l = new QLabel();
    return app.exec();
}
```

...so seemingly there is some incompatibility between poppler-qt6 and qt6 but I'm not sure how to investigate further.

Comment: The first thing I would check if the poppler library and the qt library are compiled against the same c++ runtime or against compatible ones. If that’s the case I would check if those are compatible with the one used in you vs project.

Comment: @t.niese both libraries are the latest installed via vcpkg, and both seem to depend on         MSVCP140.dll,VCRUNTIME140.dll. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 but from my research these runtimes are only supported up until Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: ***at the end of the main method causes an access violation at the Poppler::Document::load() line.*** My advice is to attempt to understand why there is an access violation and if it is reproducible file a bug report at the vcpkg site, including the access violation and other supporting information that could help the developers determine the cause.

Comment: One thing is odd that you are using this inside of `int main()` normally for a Qt application  you don't do much in `int main()`, Instead you would have your QMainWindow or some other object you allocated in your window do what you are attempting in `int main()`